# Extracting data from one grid cells to another set of grid cells

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, proximity, point-in-polygon, extract

I have my own point shapefile (each point has its lats n longs). I found a data which has lats and longs, and I imported it into ArcMap and created a shapefile which also has its own points (with lats and longs). Now I want to know whether there is a way for me to extract data from the new point shapefile I created to the older point shapefile. The thing is that the points of the two shapefiles are different (although some will accidentally match).

Is there a way I can export data from one of them to the other (especially from the new point shapefile to the old one)?

Comment: Look into the Near command to find the closest point to a point.  Identity or Intersect would link points to polygons (if they're within the poly).

Comment: please could explain further. I did not get you well.